# "0" appearing after function is completed in C++

Tags: c++

```c
// This program is able take two variables`
// and apply Auto increment or decrement`
// based on the user's input and by calling a function

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int inc (int, int); // Increment function prototype
int dec (int, int); // Decrement function prototype

int main () 
{
    int num1, num2;
    char operation = ' ', I, D;

    cout << "Enter the first variable: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second variable: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Do you want Auto increment, decrement or both? (Type 'I', 'D' or 'B'): ";
    cin >> operation;
    
    if (operation == 'I') {
        cout << inc(num1,num2);
    }
    else if (operation == 'D') {
        cout << dec(num1,num2);
    }
    else if (operation == 'B') {
        cout << inc(num1,num2);
        cout << endl;
        cout << dec(num1,num2);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error please enter 'I', 'D' or 'B' as a option" << endl;
    }

    return 0;   
}

int inc (int num1, int num2) {
    num1++; num2++;
    
    cout << "Number 1 ++ is: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "Number 2 ++ is: " << num2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

int dec (int num1, int num2) {
    --num1; --num2;
    
    cout << "Number 1 -- is: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "Number 2 -- is: " << num2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I just started taking Fundamentals of programming I at college and i have this assignment and this 0 keeps appearing after the function has completed

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: `cout << inc(num1,num2);` — you’re printing the return value of your functions.

Comment: All your functions return 0 and you explicitly use `std::cout` to print that return value

Comment: Aside: Why do you declare variables `D` and `I` in `char operation = ' ', I, D;`? Where are they used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your `inc` and `dec` print stuff, but also return  an int. You then proceed to print the return value, on these lines:

```
cout << inc(num1,num2);
```

and

```
cout << dec(num1,num2);
```

.

You can safely remove these `cout <<` prefixes, and probably the entire return value, as it does not seem necessary to output your resuls (that happens in inc and dec).

Answer (score 0):

int inc (int &num1, int &num2)
int dec (int &num1, int &num2)

Don't forget the ampersand to modify globalvariables

Comment: This isn’t an answer, it’s a comment. Furthermore, OP isn’t *trying* to modify global (or the caller’s) variables. Pass by value seems to be what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (operation == 'I') {
        cout << inc(num1,num2);
    }
    else if (operation == 'D') {
        cout << dec(num1,num2);
    }
    else if (operation == 'B') {
        cout << inc(num1,num2);
        cout << endl;
        cout << dec(num1,num2);
    }
```

In this section don't use `cout`. The function is returning `0` and you are printing it using `cout << dec(num1,num2);`.

Just call the function as you are printing the values inside the function.

```
    if (operation == 'I') {
        inc(num1,num2);
    }
    else if (operation == 'D') {
        dec(num1,num2);
    }
    else if (operation == 'B') {
        inc(num1,num2);
        cout << endl;
        dec(num1,num2);
    }
```

And also as if you want to modify `num1` and `num2` inside the functions so that the variables declared in main function is modified also, then you have to pass by reference like:

```
int inc (int &num1, int &num2) {
    num1++; num2++;
    
    cout << "Number 1 ++ is: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "Number 2 ++ is: " << num2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

int dec (int &num1, int &num2) {
    --num1; --num2;
    
    cout << "Number 1 -- is: " << num1 << endl;
    cout << "Number 2 -- is: " << num2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```